# Test Local Service Against Production Clients

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api, https, microservices

At our company we have a variety of microservices and web clients that make up our SaaS (software as a service) product.

When modifying the behavior of a specific service (usually written in C# WebApi). We would like to spot check the integration behavior against a client that makes calls to that service. As the developer working on a C# service locally, I would prefer not to have to clone and build that specific web client (with local settings to point to the local server) in order to see how it interacts with my local server changes. Ideally I could navigate to a deployed version of the client (develop, rc, prod) and redirect the requests that client is sending to the deployed version of my service to my local server instead.

I've attempted this with tools such as [requestly](http://requestly.in). However this just results in a 307 response and the following error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:59517/api/users. Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)

While we are verifying the correct behavior on the server via TDD unit tests. There are occasions where it would be nice to be able to use an already deployed client to test a local server to get a better feel for what might break in the integration tests during the automated build. Are there standard ways of doing this sort of microservice testing that does not involve local buildin/configuring of the web client?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on the occasions you want to actually test against an active end point? I have been able to solve this problems with a mock framework and TDD almost every time.